# Copy Input Box to SharePoint input

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, content-editor-web-part

Is it possible to get the value in the textbox value I created in Script Editor to copy over to Title?  I would like for the text I type to automatically copy over to the Title box that is part of the SharePoint list.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the JS code below:

```
<input id="fill" type="button" value="set value"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#fill').click(function(){

    var string1 = $("input[Title='text']").val();

    console.log(string1);

    $("input[Title='Title Required Field']").val(string1);

  });

});

</script>
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

Hope this may help :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  The thing is, I don't want to create another column in the SharePoint list for other purposes.  I would like to get the value from the Script Editor created field specifically, to copy over to the SharePoint field.  Sorry if it is a bit confusing.

Comment: This worked!  I just had to set the title in the input field.
 <input type="text" Title="testing1" id="A"/>
  <input type="text" Title="testing2" id="B"/>